# Are alarms deleted along with app that produces them?

Tags: android, alarm

I'm building an alarm clock app and I'm debugging it on my own device.
There are still a lot of bugfixes to be done, so a lot of alarms are set in the future.

Will the system still try to open the activity that produces the alarm, or Will all alarms get deleted by deleting the app?

Comment: If you delete the app then `PendingIntents` will be deleted also. I think this is what you're asking.